# all() returning a generator?

Tags: python, iterator, generator

So I want to test if a list is sorted. After reading this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710763/how-do-i-check-if-a-list-is-sorted), I did this:

```
ll = [ 0, 8, 4, 12, 2, 10, 6, 14, 1, 9, 5, 13, 3, 11, 7, 15 ]
all(b >= a for a, b in zip(ll, ll[1:]) )
```

Output

```
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x10d9ecaa0>
```

Ok so `all()` return a generator. But this is what the Python documentation says about `all()`:

> Return True if all elements of the iterable are true (or if the
>   iterable is empty)

What am i missing?

Comment: Not on Python 2.7.5, I got False...

Comment: I get `False` both in Python2 and 3

Comment: Can't reproduce either. Please give a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Perhaps your `all` got overwritten by a user-made function. If you do `print all`, does it say `<built-in function all>`?

Comment: .. and this is why no one should ever do `from numpy import *`, or use any environment which does the same.

Comment: @DSM I am using IPython notebook... Thanks for helping me find the culprit!

Comment: `ipython --pylab`  does this too (also stomps `any`)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a problem of those silly star-imports:

```
from numpy import *

ll = [ 0, 8, 4, 12, 2, 10, 6, 14, 1, 9, 5, 13, 3, 11, 7, 15 ]
all(b >= a for a, b in zip(ll, ll[1:]) )
#>>> <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f976073fdc0>
```

Python's `all` works fine.

You can access it via `__builtin__` module in python2 and `builtins` module in python3:

```
import __builtin__
__builtin__.all(b >= a for a, b in zip(ll, ll[1:]))
```