# Why sorted list detection does not work in this situation?

Tags: python, list, sorting, ipython

My goal is to have python code allowing to detect if a list is sorted or not.

I would like to understand why the following code return `True` instead of my expected guess `False`

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 7, 8, 7]
all(l[i] <= l[i+1] for i in xrange(len(l)-1)) # return "True"
```

Notes:

- I'm using python 2.6.4 inside **iPython 0.10**
- I use very huge list so I'd prefer to avoid
  solution of type `l == l.sort()`

In the way to understand this I already read (and test) info from the main two following post:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3755251/4716013
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/4710776/4716013

**EDIT:**
OK apparently the problem appear inside iPython ONLY, not when using only python command line!

**iPython 0.10**

```
In [93]: l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 7, 8, 7]

In [94]: all(l[i] <= l[i+1] for i in xrange(len(l)-1))
Out[94]: True
```

**python 2.6.4**

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 7, 8, 7]
>>> all(l[i] <= l[i+1] for i in xrange(len(l)-1))
False
```

Comment: @Ajay: can you be more specific?

Comment: @musically_ut : which version of python do you use?

Comment: @prodev_paris: Indeed I was using `Python 2.7.9`. Python 2.6 also returns `False`.

Comment: I'm also getting False on Python 2.6.6, both with the gen exp version and the list comp version. And I get the same results with Python 2.5.5.

Comment: This may be just splitting hairs, but the code you've shown neither returns nor prints anything. So if you're running this anywhere outside of a REPL, you shouldn't be seeing "True" or anything else. Are you 100% sure that this is the code that's running, and that's the line that's producing output?

Comment: Seems like an ipython bug to me.  The latest version is 3.1.  I would try upgrading.

Comment: @prodev_paris: Can you try a new ipython session and include the full output, including the header information that includes the ipython version and python version?

Comment: What does `print all.__module__` show? If it's not `__builtin__` you're using it from a different module - probably `numpy`.

Comment: @Antti Haapala: This is _pure_ iPython (called from a bash shell)

Comment: @Jon Clements `print all.__module__
--------> print(all.__module__)
numpy.core.fromnumeric`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce a similar problem on my machine. However, after digging, it occurred that the `all` function was not the built-in function but came from numpy (`all.__module__ == 'numpy.core.fromnumeric'`).

The problem is that you are creating a generator rather than a list. For example:

```
all(x>5 for x in xrange(3))
# <generator object <genexpr> at 0x1153bf7d0>

all([x>5 for x in xrange(3)])
# False

if all(x>5 for x in xrange(3)):
   print True
else:
   print False
# prints True

if all([x>5 for x in xrange(3)]):
   print True
else:
   print False
# prints False
```

Simply add `[...]` to your expression:

```
all([l[i] <= l[i+1] for i in xrange(len(l)-1)])
# False
```

If it is the case that you need to create a list, a more efficient solution would be to do a simple for loop:

```
for i in xrange(len(l)-1):
    if l[i] > l[i+1]:
        result = False
        break
else:
    result = True
```

If like me, you overrode the built-in `all` function, you can do `del all` to recover it. After that, you should have `all.__module__ == '__builtin__'`. If that's still not the case, just do `all = __builtin__.all`

Comment: That's not a problem - there's no need to create a `list` at all here - the genexp is more than fine

Comment: What version of python are you using to get this output?

Comment: How are you getting `# <generator object <genexpr> at 0x1153bf7d0>`? :) You should get and do get `False`

Comment: I get the intended results with standard Python 2.7. Are you testing these in something other than the standard Python Shell?

Comment: Python 2.7.3 (default, Feb 20 2013, 17:47:37), IPython 0.13.1

Comment: I just get False in the standard shell.  Maybe you're using something other than CPython?

Comment: @JulienSpronck: It's very likely that you've run `from numpy import *` or `from numpy import all` earlier in your ipython session.

Comment: This solution wastes memory by creating an extra list. Consider changing it to a loop which breaks as soon as any condition is violated.

Comment: @BillLynch Thanks for the insight ... let me know if the answer makes more sense now

Comment: @JulienSpronck: The larger issue is that you and prodev are still seeing different behaviors. prodev claimed that `all(l[i] <= l[i+1] for i in xrange(len(l)-1))` returned `true`, while you (correctly) claim that with numpy it returns a generator. So there's still some difference between your environment, the default environment, and whatever prodev is doing.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've presented in the question works fine:

#### Python 2.7

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 7, 8, 7]
>>> all(l[i] <= l[i+1] for i in xrange(len(l)-1))
False
```

#### Python 3.4

We substitute `range` for `xrange`...

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 7, 8, 7]
>>> all(l[i] <= l[i+1] for i in range(len(l)-1))
False
```

#### IPython 3.0.0 with Python 2.7.6

```
In [1]: l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 7, 8, 7]

In [2]: all(l[i] <= l[i+1] for i in xrange(len(l)-1))
Out[2]: False
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally it appear that a working solution in iPython 0.10 would be:

```
In [93]: l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 7, 8, 7]
In [100]: all([l[i] <= l[i+1] for i in xrange(len(l)-1)])
Out[100]: False
```

**EDIT:**
Or better: use a loop as presented in the accepted answer!

Comment: That solution wastes memory by creating an extra list. Consider changing it to a loop which breaks as soon as any condition is violated.

Comment: @musically_ut You are totally right :) the loop presented by Julien Spronck indeed appears to be a better solution for my situation (old iPython)