# What is the Pythonic way to check if a list of strings is sorted or not?

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, sorting

I have a list of strings

```
my_string_list = ['Banana', 'Apple', 'Sorry']
```

How can I check if this `my_string_list` is sorted or not?

One obvious way is to sort this list and compare it against the original list. But I do not want to iterate over the whole original list to decide that the list is not sorted.

```
sorted_list_of_strings = sorted(my_string_list)
if my_string_list != sorted_list_of_strings:
    print(f'The list {my_string_list} is not sorted.')
```

I am wondering if there is any other way to do this?

Comment: Why not `sort` it and know for sure?

Comment: I do not want to sort a list of million items just to check if it was sorted or not!

Comment: Details are important when asking a question. In this question, you omitted more than one, that would be deemed relevant to provide a meaningful answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if a list is sorted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710763/how-do-i-check-if-a-list-is-sorted)

Comment: Not exactly. This iterates over the whole list to come to a conclusion. Also, I have edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, I'd use your solution (`if x == sorted(x):`) and accept the cost; it's easy to write, and if it's not a hot code path, it hardly matters if you're doing it somewhat inefficiently (for the already-sorted case, it'll be roughly `O(n)` anyway thanks to Python's TimSort, so you only pay `O(n log n)` general sort costs for the "not sorted" case). It's also easy to customize when you need to handle reverse sorting, keyed sorting, etc., while remaining easy to write and easy to verify by inspection.

If you want a more efficient solution using Python builtins, you could do something along the lines of (with `from operator import le` at the top of the file):

```
if all(map(le, my_string_list, my_string_list[1:])):
```

which compares each element to the following element, returning `False` on the first mismatch, and `True` if they're all less than or equal to the following element. Replace `my_string_list[1:]` with `itertools.islice(my_string_list, 1, None)` if you have concerns about the cost (computational or memory cost) of building the temporary `list` with the plain slice.

Comment: This is not really efficient because `my_string_list[1:]` is a copy.  It would be better to iterate elements in pairs, or iterate `range(len(my_string_list))` and index.

Comment: @wim: Better would be to optimize it out with `itertools.islice` or manually making an iterator and advancing it once then using that iterator as the second argument, but it's just an extra `O(n)` step to slice normally, and a relatively cheap `O(n)` step at that. If necessary, `islice(my_string_list, 1, None)` would replace `my_string_list[1:]` to keep it a one-liner, but it's premature optimization unless you're doing this a lot.

Comment: I'm not talking about time-complexity, I'm talking about memory efficiency.

Comment: @wim: Sure. But again, premature optimization in most cases. If your `list` is 10,000 elements long, the incremental cost is temporary consumption of 80 KB (on a 64 bit system); hardly matters (it's always a shallow copy, so the size of the objects stored doesn't matter). `islice` avoids that issue, but I'd skip it unless I knew it was the hottest of code paths and/or the inputs would be huge. I added a note to the answer on that point just to be clear.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Awesome! `le` was the functionality I was looking for.

Comment: Your code would be just as easy to modify and verify by inspection if you used a generator expression instead of `map`.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Sure, `all(first <= second for first, second in zip(my_string_list, my_string_list[1:]))` (or `islice` equivalent) also works just fine. I may leap to `map` a little overly readily sometimes. :-)